# $\mathcal{B}_n:= \{(a, b): a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b\} \cup \{(a, b) \cup \{n\}: a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathcal{B}_n:= \{(a, b): a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b\} \cup \{(a, b) \cup \{n\}: a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}?$  How can I prove this one? In our proof for the second condition, we have a problem  in the case if both $B_1$ and $B_2$ are in the form $ \{(a, b) \cup \{n\}$ where   $x$ is not in both interval but $x = n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what you said, this is not a base.

Take $B_1=(-1,0)\cup \{2\}$ and $B_2=(0,1)\cup\{2\}$. Their intersection is $\{2\}$, but there is no base set contained in this singleton.